# jsonNodeReference and jsonPathDefinition for multiple child nodes

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to know how to apply jsonNodeReference and jsonPathDefinition for multiple child node in azure data factory

Example json data:

```
{
 "success": true,
"profiles": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "data": [
            {
             "date": "2018-11-08T00:00:00",
             "name": "sree",
             "Quantity": "10"
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-11-09T00:00:00",
                "name": "sree",
                "Quantity": "20"
            }
               ]
      },
      {
        "id": "154",
        "data": [
            {
             "date": "2018-11-08T00:00:00",
             "name": "Dhanu",
             "Quantity": "25"
            },
            {
             "date": "2018-11-09T00:00:00",
             "name": "Dhanu",
             "Quantity": "29"
            }
              ]
        }
   ]
```

}

I have tried with "jsonNodeReference":"$.['profiles']" and 
"jsonNodeReference":"$.['profiles']['data']" in the input dataset

The expected result is

```
Success Id  Date                name    Quantity
TRUE    123 2018-11-08T00:00:00 Sree    10
TRUE    123 2018-11-09T00:00:00 Sree    20
TRUE    154 2018-11-08T00:00:00 Dhanu   25
TRUE    154 2018-11-09T00:00:00 Dhanu   29
```

Answer (score 0):

ADF only supports expand one array at a time. For example, you could example profiles[0] like the following. 
$.['profiles'][0]['data']

For your scenario, I guess you could use ADF custom activity to parse it yourself.

[image]